# Zend Framework 2 - Dynamically Loading Modules and its configuration

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2, config, service-locator

I am trying to load modules on the basis of user type in addition to Application module i.e. Application modules is always loaded since it is mentioned in `application.config.php` file if user is of type 1 I want to load module A, B and D and if user is of type 2, I want to load module C, E and F.

in `Module.php` of Application module's `onBootstrap` function I load modules dynamically, and when I see the result `var_dump($moduleManager->loadedModules())`, it shows the array of the correct modules that are loaded

But the issue that I am facing is that even though modules are loaded correctly their configuration is not loaded.

**Example:**

In my module A I have a service called, `SomethingService` and it is being used in `indexAction` of `IndexController` in `Application` module. But it throws the exception which states

> Unable to fetch or create instance of SomethingService

After some debugging I found that even though the modules are loaded their configuration from `module.config.php` is not loaded and is not availble in `Config` service.

To overcome this issue, where I load module, I now get the config using `$module->getConfig()` method merge if with the **Config** service and override Config service using the following code

```
$this->serviceLocator->setAllowOverride(true);
$this->serviceLocator->setService('config', $mergedConfig);
$this->serviceLocator->setAllowOverride(false);
```

As a result of this , when I get config using `$this->serviceLocator->get('config);` I see that all the modules config is merged and is available in the **config** array.

After doing all of this, I am still getting the exception that I mentioned above. Maybe I am doing all of this at the wrong location?

Comment: Could you show me, how do you call `SomethingService` in `IndexController`?

Comment: @DollyAswin `$service = $this->serviceLocator->get('SomethingService');` Yes, serviceLocator is injected into the controller, yes service is declared in factories by the name of `SomethingService`

Comment: OK, could you show me the `service_manager` or `factories` configuration. This error caused by the service not created

Comment: @DollyAswin I did var_dump for the service I am getting error for and this is what I am getting 

`/app/module/Application/Module.php:458:string 'ModuleA\Factory\Mapper\SomethingServiceFactory' (length=37)`

Comment: That is not help, please edit the question with your `Factories` configuration, just on `ModuleA\Factory\Mapper\SomethingServiceFactory` section. And please also put the error messages. 
This error caused by the `factory` not created successfully.

Comment: @DollyAswin the issue is not with the factory or configuration values, if I load all modules by application.config.php it works without error, the issue is with dynamically loading the modules, rather than the factory or config values. :) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, if you load all modules by `application.config.php` it works without error, and the issue is with dynamically loading the modules.

And I analiyze this caused by `Application` module has been bootstraped, so your controller didn't find the `SomethingService`. Because you load modules in `onBootstrap(Event $e)` method.

> `onBootstrap(Event $e)` method is called immediately after all modules
>   have been bootstraped.

So, `IndexController` have been configured first. That's why it cannot find the `SomethingService`

I think you need to load modules in `init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)` method instead of `onBootstrap(Event $e)`.

> `init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)` is called before the module is
>   bootstrapped.

```
class Module
{
    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
    {
        // Remember to keep the init() method as lightweight as possible
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not access ServiceManager in init method, is there a way, I can load modules on `loadModules.post` event without breaking the app ?

Comment: Although I have been through this routine, I know we can load modules in  init method, but this is before the serviceManager is loaded and we can not access the services like doctrine , zendDb or zfcuser_auth_service, I need zfcuser_auth service to load modules based on user role , i hope you understand what I am trying to achieve here

Comment: @HarisMehmood  You can get the ServiceManager in the init method. Try `$sm = $e->getParam('ServiceManager');` in your modules `init()` method.

Comment: @Crisp hi, thanks for this, but even if I get `serviceManager` in `init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)` the services are not yet loaded :)